# How much sidelap is adequate for aerial imagery?

Tags: imagery, aerial-photography

How much sidelap is adequate for aerial imagery? My AOI has few buildings taller than 3 stories. I want to minimize building lean. I've seen imagery with 40% sidelap and the building lean is pretty bad along the edges. Is 60% side and endlap overkill?

Comment: Will this be done using SfM pipelines (UAV flights) or traditional orthomosaic stitching (Manned flights)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. Subjective questions are a better fit for the [chat] feature, though it is sufficiently underutilized that you might be able to garner more opinions in a different discussion-oriented community.

Comment: It would be a traditional manned flight at the county scale. 570 square miles.